# Laravel redirect not work inside Observers

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hi I need to redirect laravel code from an Observer before delete. Here is my code,

```
<?php

namespace App\Observers;

use App\Models\Product;

class ProductObserver {

/**
     * Listen to the Product deleting event.
     *
     * @param  App\Models\Product $product
     * @return void
     */
    public function deleting(Product $product) {
        try {
            \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env("STRIPE_SECRET"));

            $product = \Stripe\Product::retrieve($product->id);
            $product->delete();
        } catch (\Stripe\Error\Base $e) {
             return redirect()
               ->route("voyager.products.index")
               ->with([
                       'message'    => "Api error : ".$e->getMessage(),
                       'alert-type' => 'success',
             ]);
        }
    }

}
```

But items get deleted without redirecting. Does anyone know a way to do this?. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Observers are events and you cannot redirect from events

Comment: Redirect in the controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks so much everyone who helped. In my case it's really hard to use controller. So I did a little digging and found with `->send()` we can redirect from anywhere. I'm adding it in case anyone else also caught with the situation like this. I couldn't use Flash message also since I needed to prevent delete.

```
public function deleting(Product $product) {
        try {
            \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env("STRIPE_SECRET"));

            $product = \Stripe\Product::retrieve($product->id);
            $product->delete();
        } catch (\Stripe\Error\Base $e) {
            return redirect()
                            ->route("voyager.products.index")
                            ->with([
                                'message' => "Api error : " . $e->getMessage(),
                                'alert-type' => 'success',
                            ])->send();
        }
    }
```